# Why adjustbox needs a tweak of raise=-0.3ex with enumitem?

Tags: vertical-alignment, adjustbox

The MWE below yields the desired results. But, is there a better way to get this alignment instead of the `raise=-0.3ex`:

[image]

Without the `raise=-0.3ex`, the item number is not aligned with the text:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\fboxsep=0pt

\newadjustboxenv{MyAdjustbox}{valign=t, raise=-0.3ex}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
        \begin{MyAdjustbox}
        \fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                Some text that takes up several lines, so we need to adjust the
                item number to align with the top baseline.
            \end{minipage}%
       }%
       \end{MyAdjustbox}%
   \end{enumerate}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that there are two separate issues. The main one arises from the use of a `minipage` environment.

- The first row in the material inside the fbox has no material taller than uppercase letters. Because that material is encased in a `minipage`, the unused vertical whitespace needed for symbols such as `(` and `)` is removed. In contrast, the enumeration symbol is *not* encased in a `minipage`, and hence its baseline is chosen without removing the implicit `\strut`. If one inserts a `\strut` in the first line of the `\fbox`, most of the need for vertical adjustment is removed.
- To fully align the baselines of the "1." particle before the `\fbox` and the material inside the `minipage`, one also needs to make an adjustment (pun intended) for the thickness of the rule (given by the parameter `\fboxrule`; default value: `\arrayrulewidth`, usually `0.4pt`) that surrounds the fbox. And, since the value of `\fboxsep` is nonzero in general, I suggest using the following code

  ```
  \newadjustboxenv{MyAdjustbox}{valign=t, raise=\fboxrule+\fboxsep}
  ```

  in lieu of

  ```
  \newadjustboxenv{MyAdjustbox}{valign=t, raise=-0.3ex}
  ```

With these two adjustments (yet another pun -- ouch!), I get this screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\fboxsep=0pt

\newadjustboxenv{MyAdjustbox}{valign=t, raise=\fboxrule+\fboxsep}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{MyAdjustbox}
       \fbox{%
       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\strut%
       Some text that takes up several lines, so we need 
       to adjust the item number to align with the top 
       baseline.
      \end{minipage}%
      }%
   \end{MyAdjustbox}%
   \end{enumerate}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just fixed a slight inaccuracy: The width of the rule around an fbox is given by `\fboxrule`, not `\arrayrulewidth`. (The default values of both parameters are the same (usually: `0.4pt`) in many (most?) document classes, making it easy to conflate the two.)

Answer (score 8):

The option `valign=t` of `adjustbox` doesn't retrieve the inner top baseline as the `[t]` option of minipage or tabular do. `adjustbox` *calculates*  a height which takes the current text font size into account: by default `valign=t` sets the height to the height of the current `\strutbox`.

This means that depending on the text on the first line it can be too high or too low relative to the number. You can "repair" the first case with the code from Mico but for the second case there is no easy fix.

In my opinion `adjustbox` is the wrong environment for such boxes. It is useful for aligning pictures which have no intrinsic baseline, but not for text boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newadjustboxenv{MyAdjustbox}{valign=t}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{MyAdjustbox}%too high
             \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                aaaa
             \end{minipage}%
       \end{MyAdjustbox}
    \item  \begin{MyAdjustbox}%too low
             \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
              $\int\limits_1^3 f(x) $
             \end{minipage}%
       \end{MyAdjustbox} 
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 . :-) I hadn't even thought of the second case! BTW, I've applied a couple of typo fixes -- feel free to revert.

Comment: So, what is the recommend as the correct environment to use for such alignment issues?

Comment: Why do you need an additional environment at all?